# What is the point of Bounty Hunters in SPAZ?

Tags: space-pirates-and-zombies

I wonder what bounty hunters bring to SPAZ other than a couple of new ship hulls. What are they actually useful for? Other than adding targets for me to blow up.

I played through SPAZ a couple of times before bounty hunters were added and the game was fun. But on a recent play through with bounty hunters in the game, I wondered why the developers bothered to add them to the game. They don't seem to add anything but an occasional attack when I warp into a system, at least in the first "half" of the game. Do they become useful later? Or are they just another volunteer source of goons and data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the early stages of the game you can earn respect at their base. If you have enough you can hire them to attack a warp gate blockade.

In the second half of the game they decrease zombie fleet strength, but cost system resources.

At the cost of respect you can hire them to attack zombies.

There is achievement for killing their [stronghold](http://spacepiratesandzombies.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=Bounty_Hunter_Stronghold) in 4 chapter.